# Obtaining rates for convergence in probability from rates of convergence in expectation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_n$ $Y_n$ be a sequence of random variables such that for $C > 0$
\begin{align*}
0  \leq X_n + Y_n  \quad \text{and} \quad 
-C  \leq X_n 
\end{align*}
Suppose that for positive sequences $a_n,\, b_n \, c_n$ which converge to zero 
\begin{align*}
E(X_n) & \leq a_n \\
E(|Y_n| ) &\leq b_n \\
Y_n  & = \mathcal{O}_P(c_n)
\end{align*} 
If $c_n = o(b_n)$ is it true that $$X_n + Y_n = \mathcal{O}_P(a_n + c_n) ?$$

By Markov Inequality we get $X_n +Y_n = \mathcal{O}_P(a_n + b_n)$ but I belive there might be room for some improvement.

---

The notation $ Y_n = \mathcal{O}_P(c_n)$ is Big O in Probability notation. I.e

Given $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a constant $C >0$ and $n_0$ such that $P(|Y_n| > C c_n) \leq \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{O}_P$?

Comment: Big O in Probability notation.  Given $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $C >0$ and $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$  $P( |Y_n| > C c_n) \leq \varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $(X_n,Y_n)=(-1,1)$ with probability $b_n,$ and $(X_n,Y_n)=(b_n/(1-b_n),0)$ with probability $1-b_n.$
Note $X_n+Y_n$ is $b_n/(1-b_n)\sim b_n$ with probability tending to $1.$

For example set $a_n=b_n=1/n$ and $c_n=1/n^2.$ Then $X_n+Y_n$ is not $\mathcal O_P(1/n^2).$

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Can you think any kind of condition I can impose to $Y_n$ to obtain the desired rates?